# Understanding the pin diagram for MPU6050 IMU

Tags: pins, imu

I was reading [this tutorial](https://howtomechatronics.com/tutorials/arduino/arduino-and-mpu6050-accelerometer-and-gyroscope-tutorial/) about the MPU6050 IMU and I was unable to understand why the pin configurations vary so much when compared to [this schematic for EasyEDA.](https://easyeda.com/replicagames/mpu6050)

The tutorial has this pin configuration :

[image]

Whereas the EasyEDA schematic looks like this :

[image]

I am not sure how to reconcile the two. Why does the schematic have 24 pins while the first diagram has only 8? Also I don't know what all the 24 pins are for.

Comment: that looks like a correct schematic diagram of the MPU-6050 module ... at least, the connector pinout is the same ... what problem are you having? ... you did not ask any questions

Comment: I see 24 pins in the top diagram ... 6 pins on each of the 4  sides of the square chip ... you don't really need to know what the pins are for ... you only need to concern yourself with the pins in J1

Comment: Ah! Thanks! Missed that completely. So if I were building a schematic first, it would work fine if I were to connect the relevant 8 pins to the microcontroller and replicate the rest of the schematic as is (from the second diagram)?

Comment: it is unclear what you mean by `building a schematic first` ... if you were building your own board, then you would probably need most of the support components on that module ... if your project already ran on 3.3 V, then you would not need the regulator or the LED or one of the filter caps ... the MPU-6050 chip requires very minimal set of support components, as you can see in the schematic diagram